# $ 2\cot2x = 4$ from $0$ to $\pi$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

$$ 2\cot2x = 4$$
I need to solve this equation from $0$ to $\pi$.

I have used many trig identities and gotten down to

$$2\cos^2x - 1 = 4\sin x\cos x$$

yet I have no idea how to get it into one trig function.

Comment: But it was already one trig function. Since $\cot 2x \ne 0$, can't you write $2 = 4 \tan 2x$ and solve that instead?

Comment: $2 \cos(x^2) - 1 = \cos(2x)$ and $4 \sin(x) \cos(x) = 2 \sin(2x)$. Can you continue from here?

Comment: @Plussoyeur But that'll again lead to $\cot(2x) = 2$

Comment: Either you solve it based on @player3236 comment or if you cannot then you have to find $x$ such that $\cos(2x) = 2 \sin(2x)$ and maybe you can use a trigonometric circle to find such values?
But really you should explore player3236 road. Do you know the arctan function?

Comment: Wow, it actually did @player3236, Plussoyeur... not sure what I was doing! thank you!

Answer (score 0):

We use relation:

$$cotan(2x)=\frac{1-tan^2 (x)}{2 tan(x)}$$

So we have following equation:

$$tan^2(x)+4tan(x)-1=0$$

Which gives :

$$tan x=2 ±\sqrt 5 $$

$tan x=2+\sqrt 5 $ gives $x≈77^o$

$2 cotan(2\times 77)≈-4$

which is not acceptable.

$tan x= 2-\sqrt 5≈ -0.236$ gives $x=-13$ and $x≈180-13=167^o$

But $2cotan (-26)≈-4$

So $x=13$ can be acceptable because :

$2 cotan(26^o)≈4$

Hence solution is $x=2k \pi +\frac{13}{180}\pi$

and $x=(2k+1)\pi+\frac{13}{180}\pi$

Comment: $2 \cot (2\times 77^\circ) \approx -4.1$

Comment: I haven't been taught that relation yet. Would you mind showing me how to get there without it?

Comment: @ABCDEF $$\cot(2x)=\frac{\cos(2x)}{\sin(2x)}=\frac{2\cos^2x-1}{2\sin x\cos x}=\frac{2-\sec^2x}{2\tan x}=\frac{1-\tan^2x}{2\tan x}$$where $1-\sec^2x=-\tan^2x$.

Answer (score 0):

So if $$ 2\cot 2x = 4 \Leftrightarrow \cot 2x = 2 $$
then $$ 2x = \cot^{-1}2 + k\pi\Leftrightarrow x = \frac{\cot^{-1}2}{2} + \frac{k\pi}{2} $$
approximately we have
$$ x = 0.2318 + \frac{k\pi}{2} $$
and in range $(0,\pi)$:
$$ x \in \{0.2318, 1.8026\} $$

Comment: @player3236, thanks for correcting me.